# No package found for Undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I am trying to install angular cli as npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.9 but getting error "No matching version found for undefined" but when i tried npm view @angular/cli@6.2.9 it is showing all the details for that version.
Please help.

Comment: My node version is 10.2.1 and npm version is 6.7.0

Comment: try npm cache clean & npm cache verify
then try installing cli